# Dynamic changes to Data types in c++?

Tags: c++

I am developing a Client-Server prototype with protocol Buffers. I have two main requirements to see how efficient Protocol Buffers is and the requirements are following.

- Dynamic change of number of data elements of an array(at run-time)
- Dynamic change of data types of the structure or individual Variable (at the run time)

Do you have any idea how c++ deals with Run-time changes ?

Comment: C++ doesn't have [reflection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_%28computer_programming%29) so you can't change a type at run-time. You might, however, want to look at [Boost any](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/any.html).

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: dynamic polymorphism with a virtual `WriteToPBuffer` function might be more appropriate than Boost::Any.

Comment: @Ben voigt: Till now whatever i have done was everything has defined statically and now i need to make some changes in run time.I don't have strong idea about the C++ Run time changes capabilities, looking for experts answer how they deal with it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do you have any idea how c++ deals with Run-time changes ?

It doesn't. C++ does not have any facility to change the definition of a `struct` or `class` at runtime.

However, depending on your needs, you can use existing C++ data structures such as `std::map` to implement your own data container whose members can change at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

This answer contains only general guidelines, and I will probably get down-voted on it:

1. Use a linked-list (or any other data structure that can be used as FIFO), instead of an array.
2. Define a generic class called DataType, with a set of interface routines common to all your different data types.
3. For every data type you have, define a specific class which inherits from class DataType.
4. In each node in the linked list, store a pointer to a DataType instance; whenever you add a new entry, create a new instance of one of your data-type classes, and set the DataType pointer of the new entry to point to that instance.
5. Make sure that the destructor in class DataType is virtual, i.e., `virtual ~DataType()`.

P.S.: the guidelines above are under the assumption that you have a **finite** number of different data types defined in advanced.

Comment: I won't downvote you if you can justify using a linked list of pointers in preference to an array/vector of pointers.

Comment: As I said, general guidelines... What I meant is for OP to use a dynamic FIFO instead of a constant-size array (added that in the answer above).